# What does "This item is not reviewable." mean?

Tags: support, review

Looking at the history of reviewed questions with a pending close vote, I noticed that a page shown, "This item is not reviewable."

Does that means it is not reviewable only from me, or from anybody else?

[image: screenshot]

On *Stack Overflow*, when I watching in a review queue a post I have already reviewed, what I read is the following:

> You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.

The phrase used on ELL seems to say "this item is not anymore reviewable from anybody."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This item is not reviewable" only applies to you.

In this case, you cast the first close vote on that question which is what landed it in the review queue, so you couldn't take another review action on top of that.

Other possible causes include the post being deleted, locked, or somehow otherwise disqualified from review.

Comment: In the case of disqualified posts, the item is not reviewable from everybody, is it? Anyway, on Stack Overflow, if I have already reviewed an item, the message says so, while on ELL I didn't read a similar message. (At least, I have still to see the same message.)